# How can move product description?

Tags: magento2

I tried to copy: [image] the description
is a page where all categories are showed.[image] I imagine that I need to take the attribute.phtml and put it before or after the price but how?

Comment: show your work, we can't help you without knowing what you did

Comment: Actually, I only removed the image of the product entered into the Mangeto catalog in the file: "image with border.phtml".

"Soin du visage and Maquillage" are sub-categories.

Answer (score 0):

This is really dependent on your active theme. However you can't only modify it in the layout.xml. You must also take a look at the product `view.phtml` located at: `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: Then you need to modify `app/design/frontend/Luma/base/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: Should this file exist with the Luma theme?

Comment: @steffy97 if the Luma theme doesn't modify that file it may not be in there, but if they change that view it should be at that location. Otherwise it's in the Base theme and should be copied to the Luma theme for you to make modifications.

You may try looking into Magento theming for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try in `[Namespace]/[Your_Theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<remove name="product.info.description" />
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.main.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.price.tier">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```